# Midi Sequencer exception

Tags: java, midi

I'm trying the following,

```
 MidiDevice.Info[] devices = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        if (devices.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No MIDI devices found");
        } else {
            for (MidiDevice.Info dev : devices) {
                System.out.println(dev);
            }
        }

        Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        player.open();
```

But, I get the following,

```
Real Time Sequencer
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1078)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getReceiver(MidiSystem.java:240)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:442)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:348)
at MidiPlayTest.play(MidiPlayTest.java:23)
at MidiPlayTest.main(MidiPlayTest.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested device not installed
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDevice(MidiSystem.java:1130)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1076)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715613/midisystem-getsequencer-returns-audio-device-unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems as if there are Midi devices but those are not available, as indicated by the `MidiUnavailableException`.

Have a look at the origin of that exception, i.e. your call to `MidiSystem.getSequencer()`. In the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getSequencer%28boolean%29)on that method you'll find the following:

> **Throws:**
>       MidiUnavailableException - if the sequencer is *not available due to resource restrictions*, or no sequencer is installed in the system, or *if connected is true*, and there is *no Receiver available* by any installed MidiDevice

Continue from there, i.e. look which condition could cause that exception.

Comment: -1. OP's output shows that there are *not* midi devices present.  The `Real Time Sequencer` always appears in the list but it cannot operate alone; It needs a synthesizer or output port, and none are present.

Comment: Did suounbanks as in http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/soundbanks.html , but no get the same

Comment: any example doc for linux systems to setup all

Comment: @finnw well, I don't see the `No MIDI devices found` output

Comment: You don't see `No MIDI devices found` because `devices.length` is `1` because of the presence of `Real Time Sequencer`.  That is not the error.  The error is that the sequencer cannot be opened because there is no `Receiver`.

Comment: @finnw Well, that's what I wanted to point out: there seem to be Midi devices but there is no receiver available (see the italics in the JavaDoc quote).

Comment: Then the first part of the answer *"there are Midi devices but those are not available"* does not make sense.